# Extract sequence at specific positions with a positions file and target file

Tags: awk, extract, sequence, fasta

I have a DNA sequence-file1 (250M characters/bytes) that looks like this (FASTA format):

```
$sequence-file1
TCCTCCAAATGATGTCAGTGTCCTCCATATGATGTCAATGTCCTCCATAT
GATGTCAATATCCTCCGTATGATGTCAATATCCTCCGTATGATGTCAATA
TCCTCCATATGATGTCAGTGTCCTCTGTATGACATCAATATCCTCCATAC
GATGCCCCTGTCCTTCATATGATGTCAGTGTCCTTTTGTGAGCACCAGTG
TCCTTTGTATGACATCAGTAGTCTCCCATGAATGTCACTGTCTTCCCATA
```

and a sequence positions-file2 in this format with non-consecutive positions:

```
$positions-file2
1
2
7
39
51
```

I need to extract the characters from sequence-file1 at the positions specified in positions-file2 and  print out "position character" The following awk program:

```
$prog.file.awk    
    {
        for (i=1;i<=length;i++) 
            if((i+(NR-1)*length)==x) 
                print x"\t"substr($0,i,1);exit 
    }
```

...only does this for the first 50 lines when I pass it the positions for "x" via `xargs`:
   `xargs -I{i} awk -v x={i} -f prog.file.awk sequence-file1 < positions-file2`
Output:

```
1   T
2   C
7   A
39  T
```

Any number higher than 50 in the positions-file2 is ignored. My desired output given the above input files would be:

```
1   T
2   C
7   A
39  T
51  G
```

Also I am looking for an economical solution because for the 250M character file I have about 200M positions to match.

Comment: Huh? What does a 39 in "sequences positions2" file mean? Print the 39th what on which line? Then you say you have to "compare files" - compare which files with which and identify what? Why do you say the file has gaps?

Comment: Hi Mark, I made a small edit regarding gaps (nonconsecutive positions). The numbers in positions-file2 refer to the character number in the sequence-file1. So 39 would refer to the 39th character in file1, a 1 refers to the first character, a 100 to the 100th...

Comment: If you are outputting 5 lines for each line of your input file, there should be 25 lines of output surely?

Comment: I'm not outputting 5 lines for each line of the input file...

Comment: If you print position 1,2,7,39,51 of each line, you will get 5 lines for each line of input file surely?

Comment: How can you print position 51 when there are only 50 characters on the line?

Comment: Well I was trying to arrive at position 51 by doing the calculation `(NR-1)*length+i`

Answer (score 1):

The following will work when you have corrected your data:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{p[$1]++;next} {for(x in p)print x,substr($0,x,1)}' pf2 sf1
```

At the moment there are only 50 characters on each line so you cannot print the 51st. It also doesn't search through every character in the line, it merely extracts the ones you specify, so it will be much faster.

**Explanation**

The `FNR==NR` means that everything in the curly braces that follow applies only to the processing of file, `pf2`. In there, I save the positions in an array `p[]`, so after the positions file is read p[1]=1, p[2]=1, p[7]=1, p[39]=1 and p[51]=1.

The code in the second set of curly braces applies only to the second file, `sf1`. It loops through all the positions we saved in `p[]` and prints the selected characters from the current record by extracting them with `substr()`.

Comment: I am giving this a try with the seqeunce file re-formatted to a single 250M character line. I had tried just doing `xargs -I{i} <positions` with this format and the awk command `print x,substr($0,x,1)` but it had been very slow.

Comment: I did not scale for the problem I had. I went with a solution that involved reformatting the large files to single columns and then matching column files.

Answer (score 1):

I know the tag says awk, but awk feels like the wrong tool for the job considering the expected size of the data sets.  My C ended up a bit longer than expected but partially as I added code to validate the line termination and line length.

```
[dennis@localhost dna]$ gcc -Wall reindex.c 
[dennis@localhost dna]$ ./a.out sequence.dat position.dat
1   T
2   C
7   A
39  T
51  G
```

Seems to have worked after I copied your sequence-file1 example text to sequence.dat and 
positions-file2 to position.dat.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>


void usage(int argc,char **argv);
int analyze(
  FILE *fp 
  ,long *pLineTextLen   /**< OUT: Length of alpha text per line      */
  ,long *pLineBinLen    /**< OUT: Total length of line including lf  */
  );

int reindex(
  FILE *seqFp           /**< IN: file with sequence to reindex       */
  ,FILE *posFp          /**< IN: file with indexes to extract        */
  ,long lineTextLen     /**< IN: text to index per line              */
  ,long lineBinLen      /**< IN: characters including termintion     */
  );


int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
  int errval;
  FILE * seqFp=NULL;
  FILE * posFp=NULL;
  long   lineTextLen;
  long   lineBinLen;
  char  *sequenceName=NULL;
  int    argIdx;

  argIdx=1;

  if(argIdx >= argc)
  {
    usage(argc,argv);
    errval=-__LINE__;
    goto exiterror;
  }
  seqFp = fopen(argv[argIdx],"r");
  if(seqFp == NULL)
  {
    errval=errno;
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open %s\n",argv[argIdx]);
    goto exiterror;
  }
  sequenceName = argv[argIdx];
  argIdx++;
  if(argIdx >= argc)
  {
    usage(argc,argv);
    errval=-__LINE__;
    goto exiterror;
  }
  posFp = fopen(argv[argIdx],"r");
  if(posFp == NULL)
  {
    errval=errno;
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open %s\n",argv[argIdx]);
    goto exiterror;
  } 
  errval = analyze(seqFp,&lineTextLen,&lineBinLen);
  if(errval)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to estimate line length of %s\n"
            ,sequenceName);
    errval=-__LINE__;
    goto exiterror;
  }
  errval = reindex(seqFp,posFp,lineTextLen,lineBinLen);
  if(errval)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to reindex (errval=%i)\n"
            ,errval);
    goto exiterror;
  }


exiterror:
  if(seqFp != NULL)
  {
    fclose(seqFp);
    seqFp=NULL;
  }
  if(posFp != NULL)
  {
    fclose(posFp);
    posFp=NULL;
  }
  return(errval);

}


void usage(int argc,char **argv)
{
  (void)argc;  /* yes I'm ignoring it atm */

  fprintf(stderr,"%s {seqeuence-file} {position-file}\n"
          ,argv[0]);
  return;
}

/*********************************************************************/
/** Analyze file to determine line lenth
 * 
 * Analyze first few lines of file for identical length text
 * lines consisting only of alpha text.
 * 
 * return non-zero if lines not consistent or other error.
 *********************************************************************/
int analyze(
  FILE *fp 
  ,long *pLineTextLen   /**< OUT: Length of alpha text per line      */
  ,long *pLineBinLen    /**< OUT: Total length of line including lf  */
  )
{
  int input;
  int lineTextLen=0;
  int lineBinLen=0;
  int confirmCount=0;
  int count=0;
  enum
  {
    TEXT_READ=0,
    TERM_READ=1
  }
  state= TEXT_READ;

  do
  {
    input=fgetc(fp);
    if(input != EOF)
    {
      if(isalpha(input))
      {
        if( state == TERM_READ)
        {
          state = TEXT_READ;
          if(lineBinLen != 0 )
          {
            if( count != lineBinLen )
            {
              /* mismatch */
              goto exiterror;
            }
            confirmCount++;
          }else
          {
            lineBinLen=count;
          }
          count=0;  /* start new line */
        }
        count++;
      }
      else if( ( input == '\r' )
               || (input == '\n')
               || isblank(input) )
      {
        if(state == TEXT_READ)
        {
          state = TERM_READ;
          if(lineTextLen!=0)
          {
            if(lineTextLen  != count )
            {
              /* mismatch */
              goto exiterror;
            }
            confirmCount++;
          }
          else
          {
            lineTextLen=count;           
          }
        }
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  while(input!=EOF 
        && confirmCount<4); /* 2 text and 2 bin */
exiterror:  
  rewind(fp);
  if( pLineTextLen )
  {
    *pLineTextLen = lineTextLen;
  }
  if( pLineBinLen )
  {
    *pLineBinLen = lineBinLen;
  }

  return(confirmCount<4);  /* non-zero if not confirmed */
}

/**********************************************************************/
/** reindex sequence file to std out.
 * 
 * Print char at specified character indexes in sequence file.
 * Character indexes are one-based index of characters in 
 * seq file not including line terminations.  Line length and 
 * termination are assumed to be consistent and specified by 
 * passed parameters.
 *
 * Indexes are read as text strings one per line from pos file.
 *
 * /return non-zero on error. 
 *********************************************************************/

int reindex(
  FILE *seqFp           /**< IN: file with sequence to reindex       */
  ,FILE *posFp          /**< IN: file with indexes to extract        */
  ,long lineTextLen     /**< IN: text to index per line              */
  ,long lineBinLen      /**< IN: characters including termintion     */
  )
{
  int  errval=0;
  char buffer[80];
  char *pInput=NULL;
  long  index;
  long  lines;
  long  seekPos;
  int   sequence;

  do
  {
    pInput=fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),posFp);
    if( (pInput != NULL)
        && ( !isalnum(pInput[0]) ))  /* empty line */
    {
      pInput=NULL;
    }

    if(pInput != NULL)
    {
      index=strtol(pInput,NULL,0);
      if(index==0)
      {
        errval=-__LINE__;
        goto exiterror;
      }
      index--;  /* switch to zero based index */
      /* integer truncated division expected below */
      lines=index/lineTextLen;
      seekPos= ( ( lines * lineBinLen ) 
                 + ( index - lines * lineTextLen ) );

      fseek(seqFp,seekPos,SEEK_SET);
      sequence=fgetc(seqFp);
      if(sequence == EOF)
      {
        errval=-__LINE__;
        goto exiterror;
      }
      fprintf(stdout,"%li\t%c\n"
              ,index+1 /* convert back to one based */
              ,sequence);
    }

  }while(pInput!=NULL);

exiterror:
  return(errval);

}
```